# Setup self-hosted RocketChat on development and staging without Mongo Replica Sets?

Tags: mongodb, replicaset, rocket.chat

For rocketchat, it requires mongodb replica sets to run however we'd like to set it up on our dev and staging envs as well which do not have replicas set up. Even the mongodb website has stated thatstandalones should be used for development and staging and replicas for production: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/

So my question is, has anyone set up RC on their pre-prod environments and if so, how did you do it? Did you set up a separate mongodb server for RC and create replicas for it?

Cross-posted here: https://forums.rocket.chat/t/rocketchat-blank-screen-with-error-on-root-url-in-k8s/11470

Answer (score 0):

FWIW we added a replica set with only one primary node and no secondary nodes. That is to say that our replica set contains only one node. This satisfied Rocketchat.